# How do I get my dates to sort chronologically in my google sheets line graph?

Tags: date, google-sheets, linegraph

I am trying to create a line graph showing sales over time, but the dates are not in order. I have two line graphs, one by the date, and another by a variable I created with month and year. I don't want to sort the raw data using the menu, it is already sorted by order # and needs to stay that way. I would rather use a function if necessary. I have validated the date format for both date types using the DATEVALUE() function.

[line graphs here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSsPr.png)

Comment: Have you tried the Sort function?

Comment: How would I use that with the line graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the pivot table and click edit go to Rows > order > ascending

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks that did the trick! I was hoping to be able to run it from the raw data, I wonder why it won't read the dates like that